# How to hunt down a long running request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a customer complaining about a long running request. I found the request in the production.log but am not sure how to dig deeper into figuring out why it took so long. Is there any artifacts in the log that I should look for?

Also the DB and View times don't add up to the total request time.

Answer (score 0):

Try newrelic rpm. It can parse your logs and show you the slowest requests and a lot of other information. It shows live statistics about the app too. The trial should be enough for you to fix your application.